# Minecraft 1.6 Crash fix?

Tags: java, minecraft

This is what it shows, after I click play the launcher closes and reopens, with the following error:

```
Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)
Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
Deleting /home/user/.minecraft/versions/1.6.2/1.6.2-natives-4212631043739
```

Comment: tried reinstalling it? downloading a new version? are there any mods installed?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Please run `java -version` in a console and post the results.

Comment: Some people have trouble using OpenJDK with Minecraft. Are you using OpenJDK?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an out of date version of OpenJDK, this was happening to me too. Run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge java java7 openjdk6-jre
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install openjdk7-jre
```

In a terminal (Ctrl + Alt +T). Hope that helps!